# Jquery Jtable not working properly

Tags: jquery, jquery-jtable

I am using jquery jtable. It was working fine before. but after I cleared browser cache, it displays a message called 
"A script on this page may be busy, or it may have stopped responding. You can stop the script now, or you can continue to see if the script will complete.

Script: http://hostname.com/FRC/js/jquery-1.11.1.js:5730"

It also does not display any Page numbers.

I am using FireFox browser.
I have following JSP.

```
     <!DOCTYPE html> 
<%@ taglib prefix="c"  uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="fn" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" %>


<html>
<head>
<title>  Report Raw Data </title>
</head>


 <link rel="stylesheet" href="<c:url value="/css/jtable.css" />" type="text/css" >
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="<c:url value="/css/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.css" />" type="text/css" />

 <!--  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.js"  ></script>  -->
 <script  type="text/javascript"   src="<c:url value="/js/jquery-1.11.1.js" />" ></script>    
 <script  type="text/javascript"   src="<c:url value="/js/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.js" />" ></script>

 <script  type="text/javascript"   src="<c:url value="/js/jquery.jtable.js" />" ></script>
 <script  type="text/javascript"   src="<c:url value="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/json2/20140204/json2.js" />" ></script>

  <c:set var="baseURL" value="${pageContext.servletContext.contextPath}" />
 <script>
 var j = jQuery.noConflict();


j(document).ready(function(){   


  j('#rawDataTableId').jtable({

        paging : true, //Enable paging
        pageSize : 0, //Set page size (default: 10)   
        actions : {

                 listAction: '${baseURL}/reportRawDataPaginationDataTables.html',
        },
         fields: {
             visitType1 : {
                    title : 'Visit Type',
                    width : '30%',
                    key : true,
                    list : true,
                    edit : false,
                    create : true
                },
                visitorId : {
                        title : 'Visitor Id',
                        width : '30%',  
                        edit : false,
                        create : false,
                         display:function(data){
                               return data.record.visitor.visitorId;
                       }
                    } 
         }


    });
    j('#rawDataTableId').jtable('load');  


});




</script>


<body>

<br><br><br><br>



 <div id="rawDataTableId">
 </div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Quick thing: your link is broken

Comment: This is my internal application link. You dont have to click it. Its just a part of error message.

Comment: Ok. But if it stopped working after clearing the cache, and you didn't change anything on the code, then try in another browser, etc.

Comment: I tried IE8 as well. Its the same issue. Technically my application has to work on IE8.

Comment: But you said it was working before until you clear the cache. How would that be relevant if it's also not working in others browsers? On the other hand, the code looks find to me and I've used jtable sometimes.

Comment: This code does not work on IE8 and Firefox. If I am missing any required jquery library or if any of my library is wrong then please let me know.

Comment: I don't think you are missing anything. What I think it's going on is that there is an add-on on firefox messing with your code. Check this link: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/warning-unresponsive-script ..... And regardding ie8 check jquery documentation for compatibility. I hope this solve your issue.

Comment: I debugged the UI and noticed that value for currentPageCount is infinity

Comment: I don't know what else I can tell you at this point. That's why I'm commenting instead of writing an answer. For me it looks more like a firefox issue. The link I provided you before, came up right away after googling the error message. One more thing you can do is clearing as much as possible the code, leaving just the strictly necessary code and commenting the rest, to find out what line of code (if any) is causing the infinite script. Yet I think is a browser thing. I'm at home now and thus I'm out for today. Good luck and post the solution if you find it :)

Comment: I found the issue. I had set pagesize to zero